# I want to redirect my url to a new url every-time randomly from my selected urls

Tags: html

I want to redirect the domain to the number of selected URLs from my list

Take a look at this
[Click Here](https://www.forexxap.com/)

every time you click on the link it will take you to another post in that domain

I want to do the same but I don't know how to do that

please help me out here
thanks

i tried to redirect the domain to multiple URLS but i cant figure out how it works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

hey Uzair memon you can use js for something like this

```
let myArray = ["https://firstLink","https://secondLink","https://thirdLink"]
let randomValue = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

and refrence the randomValue in you html